# Rust Tauri command missing field even though it is provided

Tags: rust, tauri

I'm creating a [tauri](https://tauri.app) app. I want to call a [command](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command/) with some data (see code snippets below). But when I do I get the following error. This is weird since the field is provided as you can see (and tauri changes it to `snake_case` in the background). Could this have another cause?

```
ERROR invalid args `data` for command `decrypt_local_database_with_pin`: missing field `cause_error`
```

> I should note that the property in question `cause_error` and the
> `thread.sleep` call are there to help me test this application until the backend is ready.
> So there is no real functionality, yet.

These are the code parts in question:

**The Rust Part**

```
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
pub enum CommandError {
    #[error(transparent)]
    Error(#[from] anyhow::Error),
}

impl Serialize for CommandError {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> where S: Serializer,
    {
        serializer.serialize_str(self.to_string().as_ref())
    }
}

pub type CommandResult<T, E = CommandError> = anyhow::Result<T, E>;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct CommandValue<T> {
    pub cause_error: bool,
    pub values: T
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct DecryptLocalDatabaseWithPinData {
    pub pin: String,
}

#[tauri::command]
pub fn decrypt_local_database_with_pin(data: CommandValue<DecryptLocalDatabaseWithPinData>) -> CommandResult<String> {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2000));

    match data.cause_error {
        true => Ok(format!("Local database decrypted with pin: {}", data.values.pin)),
        false => Err(CommandError::Error(anyhow::anyhow!(format!("Local database was not decrypted with pin: {}", data.values.pin)))),
    }
}
```

**The Typescript Part**

```
encryptLocalDatabaseWithPin(pin: string) {
    return invoke("decrypt_local_database_with_pin", {
        data: { pin },
        causeError: true,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have structured your types and arguments wrong. With the Tauri command you've specified, you'd need to call it like this:

```
invoke("decrypt_local_database_with_pin", {
    data: { values: { pin }, cause_error: true },
});
```

And thus the error is correct: you *provided* `cause_error`, but in the wrong place.

Additionally:

- I've added `values` because that is how your Rust types are built, you can use `#[serde(flatten)]` to avoid that if you wish.
- The `cause_error` should be in snake_case; Tauri will translate the *argument* names between snake_case and camelCase, but not the *contents* of the values passed. Right now `data` is the only "argument" and what it holds will be un-touched. You can use `#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]` to avoid that if you wish.

If you were to want `causeError` to work as you tried, it would have to be a separate parameter on the command:

```
#[tauri::command]
pub fn decrypt_local_database_with_pin(data: ..., cause_error: bool) -> ...
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. Apparently I was to in my head last night.